# Get average value of a range of cells where another cell's value is greater than a number

Tags: excel-formula

How to find average value of cells in column B, but only for the values of cells in column A that is greater than or equal to n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A100,">=100",B1:B100)
```

Replace the cell numbers and the >=100 with the values you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You want AVERAGEIF():

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A,">"&E1,B:B)
```

[image]